# Allocate total to "accounts" based on percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

Using Excel 2010. I have a list of people in column A, and a list of associated totals in column B. Each person's total is going to be divided between X amount of accounts.

**Example**: Bill owes $1000.00. Accounts 1, 2 and 3 are going to pay an equal share of his total.

I then have a second sheet listing each account, and I would like calculate the total each account is going to be paying.

**Example**: Account #4 is paying 50% of Mary's total, 33% of Eric's total and 75% of Andy's total.

---

Example of details sheet:

```
Name    Total      Acc1      Acc2         Acc3        Acc4

Bill    1000.00      33%      33%          33%
Mary   2000.00                50%                     50%
```

Example of summary sheet:

```
Account             Total

Acc1                333.33
Acc2                1333.33
Acc3                333.33
Acc4                1000.00
```

---

I know I could hand enter the formulas for the account totals, but I have a lot of accounts, and doing it all manually would take hours.

Any way to get this result with a copiable formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a layout as below, try `=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$B4,C2:C4)`  (copied across)

[image: SO18000179 example]

The headings (C1:F1) can be copied and transposed to A7:A10 but the values would need to be dragged to B7:B10 individually - from where the array (A7:B10) can be copied and Paste Special Values into a different sheet.

Comment: There's no way to have C5:F5 transpose to B7:B10 automatically?

Comment: I was able to transpose them using an array formula referencing C5:F5.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Select the column array to transpose to (in your example B7:B10), enter formula =TRANSPOSE(C5:F5), then press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to make it an array formula. Works in Excel 2013 as well. Thanks ;)